# Is there a way to run my own coded tests using TestProject.io agent?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, test-project, testproject.io

I have TestProject.io agent installed on my system and I can record tests, how ever I want to run my own coded python selenium tests, how can I do it? is that an option? will I get reports locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use TestProject Python OpenSDK.
You can see the documents here:
https://docs.testproject.io/testproject-sdk/opensdk-v2/python-sdk